# Resource mapping issue in Spring Data JPA microservice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use the `findAll()` method in my controller. I wrote a repository, model and a controller as an example. However, when I am running the URL showing "This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback"

My controller is:

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

@Autowired
UsersRepository userRepo;

@GetMapping("/loadAuthUsers")
public List<Users> checkLogin() {
    return (List<Users>) userRepo.findAll();
}
}
```

My model is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    public String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String password;

    @Column(name = "uia_token")
    public String uia_token;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUia_token() {
        return uia_token;
    }

    public void setUia_token(String uia_token) {
        this.uia_token = uia_token;
    }
    public User() {
    }
    public User(Integer userId, String username, String password , String 
uia_token) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.uia_token = uia_token;
    }
}
```

And my repository is,

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

And my application.properties contain,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/espace
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgresql
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
server.port=8081
```

And my main class is,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.milletech.services.repository")
public class EspaceCheckAuthenticationApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EspaceCheckAuthenticationApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

How can I solve this mapping issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per log, it auto-wiring error.

You need to annotate ***UserRepository*** class with ***@Repository*** for available to for autowiring.

Working code would be:

```
@Repository 
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

And add annotation ***@EnableJpaRepositories*** to Spring application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried. But not working. I updated my new code in question.can you please check?

Comment: Can you also put your application.properties for DB settings

Comment: I have also put changes for Application class...apply them too

Comment: And add spring.jpa.database= postgresql to application properties

Comment: I tried , but that also not working.But when I added @RestController that making error. When I removed that annotation, it running without error. But mapping not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161159/discussion-between-prince-varghese-and-yogi).